# No running JVMs have been detected in the selected container

Tags: kubernetes, jvm, jprofiler

All,

I'm testing the kubernetes function on the latest JProfiler distro and I get the following message after selecting the container.

> No running JVMs have been detected in the selected container that have been started by the current user.
>
> It Looks like the /etc/passwd in the container does not contain an entry for the user id the container runs with.
>
> The JVM cannot provide attach functionality in this case.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> /etc/passwd in the container does not contain an entry for the user id the
> container runs with.

You have to add an entry to /etc/passwd for the user ID that the container runs with.